# how to access the form data done on a post request in the views using ajax jquery

Tags: django

I'm trying to figure out the best way to send post data to a Django View function.

What I have currently in my jquery code is something like this:

```
in the jquery:

function ajax_request(type) {
 var a="{{parameter}}";
  alert(type);
  var frm = $('#form1');
  form_data=frm.serialize();
  alert(form_data);
  $.ajax({
    type : type,

    data: form_data,
    url : geturl(a),

    dataType : 'json',

)}
```

i have written i single function called ajax_request. all i need is just access the data i have retrieved in the jquery in my views. how could i get it in my views.

```
 function event_page_load() {
alert("hi");
  ajax_request('GET')
   }

  function click_submit_button() {
  ajax_request('POST')
  }

  function ajax_request(type) {
   var a="{{parameter}}";
   alert(type);
  var frm = $('#form1');
  form_data=frm.serialize();
  alert(form_data);

  $.ajax({
    type : type,

    data: form_data,
    url : geturl(a),

    dataType : 'json',

    error : function(result) {
         alert("error");
        // alert("Error occured!!");

    },

    success : function(result,data) 
    {
        alert("success");
        // alert("data");
        // $('#container').html(data);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
            marginRight: 220,
            marginBottom: 75,
            marginLeft:100,
            marginTop:80

    },
    title: {
        marginTop:90,
        text: 'Power Consumption Vs Generator Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {

        categories: result[0]

    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Units Of Time'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Truepower Consumed',
        data: result[1]},
    {
        name: 'Generator Consumed',
        data:result[2]}],
  });

        }

 })



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.post`

```
 $.post({
         geturl(a),
         { data: form_data, dataType : 'json' },
          // response handler 

});
```

Example :

```
  $.post()  
    $("#post").click(function(){  
        $("#result").html(ajax_load);  
        $.post(  
            loadUrl,  
            {language: "php", version: 5},  
            function(responseText){  
                $("#result").html(responseText);  
            },  
            "html"  
        );  
    });
```

A helpful tutorial is available at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Complete list of Django + AJAX examples are available at https://github.com/sivaa/django-jquery-ajax-exmaples

Comment: u mean write separately for GET and POST in jquery? and im not using php.

Comment: For jQuery, PHP/Django doesn't matter :)

Comment: ok but could u tel me the way i wrote is correct. second time i posted my code. or could u el me the changes i could do for my code. Im new to using jquery , Ajax

Comment: You can refer the examples for using $.ajax() at https://github.com/sivaa/django-jquery-ajax-exmaples/blob/master/django-jquery-ajax/templates/advanced.html